# How do I add the file size to a view?

Tags: views, files

After reading and searching through related topics, I have not seen any clear answer about how to show the file size in a Views created file list. Im using Drupal 7 and having File 7.14 field installed.

I was expecting to select a field in Views in order to show it as a third column in a list of files that can be downloaded (after Title and File).

I am not a programmer, and the only related issues I've seen so far is about editing php files.

Currently, as administrator, I see the file size when I edit the node containing the file. Why can this value not be used other than in edit mode?

---

To be complete I've added the query how it is now:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language,   file_managed_file_usage.filesize AS file_managed_file_usage_filesize, 'node' AS  field_data_field_file_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node  
LEFT JOIN {file_usage} file_usage ON node.nid = file_usage.id AND file_usage.type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN {file_managed} file_managed_file_usage ON file_usage.fid = file_managed_file_usage.fid
WHERE (((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('file'))))
ORDER BY node_title ASC  
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Comment: Did you ever get the issue resolved for file sizes on multiple files? I too have that same issue.

Comment: Hi Adrew. No the issue is still there, but I have to admit that after my additional question about that was deleted here, I didn't put much effort in investigation this further. I had to post another questions at http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/45292/how-to-show-filesize-when-content-type-contains-more-than-one-file and received one reply from someone that got this working.

Answer (score 15):

Try creating a reference to the file.

Under **Advanced** in your View, and add a relationship (select *File Usage: File*).  If you now go to add a new field in your view, you should see a few more options under File, one of them being *File: Size*.

Comment: Thank you for your great explanation which get me to put a third column containing file sizes. However, some of my content types contain 2 files. In the view only the filesize of the first file is shown, not the other ones. Any idea how to fix that?