# How to show filesize when content type contains more than one file?

Tags: views, nodes, files

I'm using Drupal 7 and having File 7.14 field installed.I have a content type (named file) containing more than 1 file. I have a view that shows the filesize of all the files of the content of that content type named file. 
For doing that I have added  a relationship in Views to "select File Usage: File"
The filesize is nicely shown for content that contains only one 1 file.

However for content containing more than 1 file the filesize is only shown for the first file but not for the 2nd 3th etc.

Here is how my query currently looks like:

```
SELECT node.title AS node_title, node.nid AS nid, node.language AS node_language,   file_managed_file_usage.filesize AS file_managed_file_usage_filesize, 'node' AS  field_data_field_file_node_entity_type
FROM 
{node} node  
LEFT JOIN {file_usage} file_usage ON node.nid = file_usage.id AND file_usage.type = 'node'
LEFT JOIN {file_managed} file_managed_file_usage ON file_usage.fid = file_managed_file_usage.fid
WHERE (((node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('file'))))
ORDER BY node_title ASC  
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

Can anybody explain me how to change the View settings so that the filesizes of the other files are also be visible?

Answer (score 0):

Actually it works fine for me without additional settings

**My configuration :**

1. I used `content-type : Article` and create some fields `file`
2. Your first step is good, you need to add a relationship `select File Usage: File`
3. Then in your fields section you can add : `Content: Title` , `File: Size`, `File: Name`
   [image: settings]
   [image: result]

I have a listing of all the name of the file with their size.
If you want you can group by `Articles`.
[image: result2]